# .de domain resolving to wrong server with CloudFlare

Tags: cloudflare

My site, attacktheblock-film.de, is currently showing a Minecraft page (see yadi.sk/i/56w_DCEC3H7S9m ), which is 104.24.121.19 .

The correct server is 167.114.172.148 .

The domain is using CloudFlare as the nameserver. CloudFlare reports that its resolving correctly to 167.114.172.148 on their end (see below).

I've contacted my hosting provider. He has no idea what's up with the domain and states that it is resolving incorrectly on his end. I contacted DENIC, the company that owns .de. They deny responsibility even though, I'm pretty sure, there's no other party at fault.

So, does DENIC just not work with CloudFalre? Anyone know what to do?

> Thanks for contacting Cloudflare support.
>
> As checked, your origin redirects to traffic
>   attacktheblock-film.de/index.php?r=site/page&view=home as below, thus
>   you need to check this with your hosting provider.
>
> $ curl -svo /dev/null attacktheblock-film.de/ --resolve
>   attacktheblock-film.de :80:167.114.172.148
>   * Added  attacktheblock-film.de :80:167.114.172.148 to DNS cache
>   * Hostname  attacktheblock-film.de was found in DNS cache
>   *   Trying 167.114.172.148...
>   * TCP_NODELAY set
>   * Connected to  attacktheblock-film.de (167.114.172.148) port 80 (#0 ) GET / HTTP/1.1 Host:  attacktheblock-film.de
>
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0 Accept: */*
>
> < HTTP/1.1 302 Found < Date: Thu, 06 Apr 2017 05:30:25 GMT < Server:
>   Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) < Set-Cookie:
>   PHPSESSID=5hlhqbftjgo24v55fjig8d0ul1; path=/; HttpOnly < Expires: Thu,
>   19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT < Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache,
>   must-revalidate < Pragma: no-cache < Location: 
>   attacktheblock-film.de/index.php?r=site/page&view=home
>
> < Content-Length: 0 < Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 <
>   * Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
>   * Connection
>
> ## 0 to host attacktheblock-film.de left intact
>
> Please let us know if you have anything else we can help with.
>
> Song  Support Engineer | Cloudflare

Comment: Well, if 167.114.172.148 is your IP, Minecraft *is* running as the default virtualhost. If you didn't install that, someone either hacked your server to run Minecraft, your hosting company switched your IP without telling you, or a number of other less likely scenarios. Doesn't appear to have anything to do with DENIC.

Comment: 104.24.121.19 is just a CloudFlare server sitting in front of your real server's 167.114.172.148 IP. That's exactly how it's supposed to work. Issue is on your or your host's end.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be working properly to me. I think the problem is your understanding. Look at [this](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205177068-Step-1-How-does-Cloudflare-work-).

Both your domain http://attacktheblock-film.de and your IP 167.114.172.148 show the same contents, Minecraft server.

Your domain initially resolves to a CloudFlare IP, by design. CloudFlare acts as a reverse proxy. When the request hits the CloudFlare IP it requests the content from your server then sends it to the browser that requested the information. It caches static resources.

If you want CloudFlare to act as a simple DNS server go into the DNS page and click the orange cloud to turn it gray.

Comment: Ughh... no. My server is not 167.114.172.148. That's someone else's server.